# How can I use "SeekableByteChannel" to read a large text file line by line

Tags: java

How can I use **SeekableByteChannel** to read a large text file (size 10 GB) line by line. Number of bytes in each line is not fixed and unknown to me. I want to read each line at a time. Please help.

Comment: Why must you use a `SeekableByteChannel `?

Comment: Is it possible to use `SeekableByteChannel` in this scenario? Otherwise, I will try other methods.

Comment: Of course - you need to read bytes until you find a linebreak. But you'd need to do this manually. Something like a `BufferedReader` would be much easier. Or, even better, [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-).